# How can I "animate" modifications in the string property of a CATextLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, catextlayer

When I instanciate a `CATextLayer`, and change the `string` property from "hello world" to "hello world!!" then I do see the change in the resulting ui, but it is not subtle. It jumps out of my face.

So I'm trying to animate this change smoothly, so that the end user see a nice change for the newly added characteres.

When I'm trying to animate this change, using UIView.animate() and instiating a CABasiceAnimation for the key "string", then nothing is animated anyway.

Do you know a way so that I can have a smooth transition when adding characters to a string of a CATextLayer please?